# Troubleshooting error mounting /dev/sda2 after hard shutdown on Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk

My system froze just now and I had to do a hard shutdown, held down power until it shut down, and now I can't access my second drive. I'm kinda worried that I have completely borked it somehow. :/
I'm using Kubuntu 23.04 and when I try to access my HDD through Dolphin I get the error: `An error occurred while accessing 'Volume', the system responded: The requested operation has failed: Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/andy/Volume: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sda2` 'Volume' being the HDD.
I've got two drives, an SDD with my OSs and an HDD for data storage. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this or have I completely effed it up? (All my important data is on that drive)

lshw has this to say about the drive:

```
*-disk:0
                description: ATA Disk
                product: OOS3000G
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: OOS1
                serial: 00000000
                size: 2794GiB (3TB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=574a92c5-f9b0-4de4-9a9c-634aaf33cb03 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
              *-volume:0
                   description: reserved partition
                   vendor: Windows
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   serial: a951c6bd-7404-48fe-9ac7-86c843443b98
                   capacity: 15MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
                   configuration: name=Microsoft reserved partition
              *-volume:1
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   vendor: Windows
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: 6a32079b-a72a-ce4d-a806-8b89478926cf
                   size: 746GiB
                   capacity: 2794GiB
                   capabilities: ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2019-10-04 11:36:53 filesystem=ntfs label=Volume name=Basic data partition state=dirty
```

fdisk -l gives the following with sda1 and sda2 being my HDD.

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 18,45 MiB, 19341312 bytes, 37776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 72,99 MiB, 76537856 bytes, 149488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 242,15 MiB, 253915136 bytes, 495928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 460,39 MiB, 482750464 bytes, 942872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 55,61 MiB, 58314752 bytes, 113896 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 72,99 MiB, 76537856 bytes, 149488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 96,99 MiB, 101699584 bytes, 198632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 2,73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: OOS3000G        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 574A92C5-F9B0-4DE4-9A9C-634AAF33CB03

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  32768 5860530175 5860497408  2,7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.


Disk /dev/sdb: 476,94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: JAJS600M512C    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A18D95E8-A535-4A0E-9C3C-D924DF33BC39

Device         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1  585299968  586348543   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  586348544  743878655 157530112  75,1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3     468992  585298157 584829166 278,9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  743878656  996020223 252141568 120,2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5  996020224 1000215182   4194959     2G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/loop12: 91,69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 49,84 MiB, 52260864 bytes, 102072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 460,56 MiB, 482930688 bytes, 943224 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 389,83 MiB, 408768512 bytes, 798376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 183,5 MiB, 192409600 bytes, 375800 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 164,82 MiB, 172830720 bytes, 337560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 106,68 MiB, 111857664 bytes, 218472 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 168,22 MiB, 176390144 bytes, 344512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Is `/dev/sda2` the correct partition to be mounted? If so: Did you run `fsck` on it? That is what you should do. If you do not have a backup of the data and are afraid that `fsck` schreds (part of) the data in that partition: Make an image backup first or set up a wriitable snapshot (`dmsetup`) and run `fsck` on the snapshot. If it fixes the snapshot without destruction, throw away the snapshot and run it against the real partition.